# Send E-mail in background on Click event

Tags: android, email

i would that when the user click on a button, the app in background send an email. The user know that when he click the email is sended but he must only click. Gmail or other email's app must not opened.
I have found [this](http://www.jondev.net/articles/Sending_Emails_without_User_Intervention_%28no_Intents%29_in_Android) tutorial. But i see that it is very old (2009). Have anyone a better tutorial or is this one ok?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sending Email in Android using JavaMail API without using the default/built-in app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020088/sending-email-in-android-using-javamail-api-without-using-the-default-built-in-a)

Answer (score 0):

One way to do is to use amazon SES service. You can get it for free but there are some limits on how many emails you can send before you upgrade.

So basically you need to have amazonses jar added to your gradle build or android project.
Using their library you would need to have internet access permission in your app.

You can checkout [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforandroid/developerguide/setup.html)

Amazon SES is part of Amazon AWS

Answer (score 0):

Use this Java Class:

> javax.mail.Authenticator

Or you can use this [library](https://github.com/kristijandraca/BackgroundMailLibrary)